# What happened to the this type of naming convention?

Tags: naming, hungarian, coding-style

I have read so many docs about naming conventions, most recommending both Pascal and Camel naming conventions. Well, I agree to this, it's ok. This might not be pleasing to some, but I am just trying to get your opinion on why you name your objects and classes in a certain way.

What happened to this type of naming conventions, and/or why are they bad?

I want to name a structure, and I prefix it with "struct". My reason is that, with IntelliSense, I see all structures in one place, and anywhere I see the struct prefix, I know it's a "struct":

```
structPerson
structPosition
```

another example is the enum, although I may not prefix it with "enum", but maybe with "enm":

```
enmFruits
enmSex
```

again my reason is that in IntelliSense, I see all my enumerations in one place.

Because .NET has so many built-in data structures, I think this helps me do less searching. Note that I used .NET in this example, but I welcome language agnostic answers.

Comment: This type of notation is known as Systems Hungarian notation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation#Systems_vs._Apps_Hungarian

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/79024/15464

Comment: See: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/102689/what-is-the-benefit-of-not-using-hungarian-notation

Comment: I had the same "what happened to Hungarian?" question too.  I [wrote-up my findings and considerations here](http://reconvolution.blogspot.com/2014/07/what-happened-to-hungarian-notation.html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Joel wrote a good article on this

[Making Wrong Code Look Wrong](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html)

In short, you want to use Apps Hungarian, not Systems Hungarian notation.

Because really, who cares if it's an int, or a long, or whatever, all I care about is the "kind" of value, not it's type.

Comment: Note that the use in the question is the version Joel (and pretty much everybody else) doesn't like.

Answer (score 4):

That is Hungarian notation. Its still used but much less so now in languages where the IDE helps you with types. (ie C# Java). In those langagues the information given by the prefix is already provided by the IDE so is deemed unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

The "type" of types shouldn't matter. `class`, `struct`, and `enum` are only meaninful to the definition - you shouldn't be using something differently just because it's a `struct` and not a `class`, nor should you refer to it as one.

I think the most sensible way to use "hungarian notation" is to only seperate types from functions:

- `types`
- `instances of types`
- `functions`

Comment: Interface types and class types behave similarly in many contexts, but in some cases are semantically very different.  Likewise struct instances and class instances.  Further, the `Char[]` held by `String` has very different semantics from the the `Char[]` held by `StringBuilder`.  I would posit that if things aren't the same, similarity among them often increases rather than decreases the likelihood of confusion in the absence of a naming convention.

Answer (score 2):

If the types have appropriate names in the application domain, then the underlying representation is not important.  I much prefer code that reads like either prose or mathematics.  In English we say "Post Office", not "officePost", so I prefer "EmailService" to "serviceEmail".

Answer (score 1):

In object oriented programming languages, this "Systems Hungarian Notion" hardly has any place at all. Consider languages where everything is an object. You could rightfully use a prefix like "obj" for every variable, since *everything is an object*. But even if you use "int" and "dbl" for integer and double variables, what about the zillions of other objects? Would you invent a prefix for each and every class in your program and all the libs it uses? Or would you use a completely meaningless prefix like "obj"? Neither option makes much sense.